# throw PlatformException(code: errorCode, message: errorMessage as String, details: errorDetails, stacktrace: errorStacktrace);

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart

I am getting the error when Selecting on map https://ibb.co/BgsCPnh

Using google_maps_flutter plugin on flutter project

Comment: Please post your code so that the problem would be more clear. It is difficult to look in image.

Answer (score 1):

If you get this when you are trying to add google sign-in functionality in your flutter app via using firebase make sure you enable google sign option in authentication

-if yes then try to add SHA1 key in your firebase project

> **for getting keys**

**If you are on Mac, open terminal and type the command:**

```
keytool -list -v
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

**If you are on Windows:**

```
keytool -list -v
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%.android\debug.keystore
```